# Animate div back to its original position (cycle needs to be repeated)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've the following **HTML**

```
<div id="mrdiv"/>
<input type="button" style="position: absolute;top: 100px;"onclick="one();"></input>
<input type="button" style="position: absolute;top: 100px; left: 50px;" onclick="two();"/>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function one(){
$("#mrdiv").stop(true).animate({right: "+=214"},200);
}

function two(){
$("#mrdiv").stop(true).animate({left: "+=214"},200);
}
```

**CSS**

```
#mrdiv{
    position:absolute;
    background-color: black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Last but not least: http://jsfiddle.net/25pYY/3/
For some odd reason, I can't understand why the buttons don't work but I guess the code is enough to understand what I want.

Basically, when I execute the animate functions the div animate properly but only in the first passage to the code. With this I mean that If I click the button **one** then two won't work, or vice-versa. I need them both to work and to do this repeatdly but I don't understand why they wont. Any ideas on this one? Sorry for the broken fiddle, I'll try and get it to work while waiting!

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError: one is not defined"

Comment: "Uncaught Reference: **I can't understand why the buttons don't work but I guess the code is enough to understand what I want.** (...) **Sorry for the broken fiddle, I'll try and get it to work while waiting!**" :p

Comment: Here's a fiddle that works. You need to load your functions into the head. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/25pYY/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `right` and `left` values are competing with each other. You need to disable them as appropriate:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/25pYY/9

```
function one() {
    $("#mrdiv").stop(true).animate({
        right: "+=14"
    }, 200).css('left', 'auto');
}

function two() {
    $("#mrdiv").stop(true).animate({
        left: "+=14"
    }, 200).css('right', 'auto');
}
```

It would be a good move to get your click handlers out of your HTML, like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/25pYY/10

```
$(function () {
    $('#mrdiv input').click(function () {
        if ($(this).index() == 1) {
            one();
        } else {
            two();
        }
    });
});
```

As I suspected, you actually wanted different behavior than what your code would indicate. Here's how you might keep the animations from jumping to the sides of the screen. Only animate one property:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/25pYY/12

```
function one() {
    $("#mrdiv").stop(true).animate({
        left: "-=14"
    }, 200);
}

function two() {
    $("#mrdiv").stop(true).animate({
        left: "+=14"
    }, 200);
}
```

Comment: Answer updated to move property resets outside the animate method.

Comment: that's not exactly what I want... I want it to animate 14px to the right and left alternatively, that fiddle only bounces to the extreme os client.width()

Comment: I followed your lead. You'll want to only modify `left`, then.

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/25pYY/12/ You'll need to add logic to keep it on the screen.